# Spring MVC, не попадаю в контроллер

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Начал изучать Spring MVC, по урокам сделал всё, никаких проблем с развертыванием нет, в файл главной страницы, которая была создана автоматически (index.jsp), через localhost:8080/ попадаю.
Но вот при попытке попасть в контроллер, прописанный через RequestMapping не получается.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>example-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

example-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.uraty.trainingplan.controllers"/>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ExampleCtrl {
    private int counter;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String request(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("visitorsCount", counter++);
        System.out.println("I'm here");
        return "index.jsp";
    }
}
```

[image: Структура]

Судя по окну Output в Idea (а там нет никакой надписи I'm here) я в контроллер вообще не попадаю.
Ах, да ещё подчеркивается return "index.jsp" с надписью No view resolvers found. Попробовал добавить в example-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
</bean>
```

Однако ничего не изменилось.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: а вы чем деплоите? возможно вам надо вбивать имя_приложения/index

Comment: Та без понятия, я всё провожу в Idea, пока что даже без Maven, указал сервер tomcat в Run configurations. Application contex прописано как "/". То есть вроде никакого названия не нужно

Comment: Ну я про идею и спрашивал. Если проставили "/" то адрес правильный. Пробовали ли вы то что вам предложили в ответах? Если да, то отпишитесь про результат.

Comment: Безуспешно всё (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил. Проблема оказалась примитивна до ужаса. Нужно было включить библиотеки спринга в выходной файл. Там в менюшке структуры проекта в артефактах. Пипец. Ни одной ошибки не выводилось, ни одной подсказки. Это мне начисто вынесло мозг.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте в контроллере заменить на `return "index";` вместо `return "index.jsp";`

Так же поддержки аннотированных методов в контроллере в `example-servlet.xml` следует добавить `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` с соответствующими схемами. 
И, возможно, стоит указать `InternalResourceViewResolver'y` **где** именно лежат представления. Допустим, что все страницы JSP для приложения находятся в каталоге `/WEB-INF/`. Тогда настройка бина будет такой:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Когда `DispatcherServlet` запросит у `InternalResourceViewResolver`'a JSP - страницу, то он добавит к имени приставку */WEB-INF/* и окончание .jsp. Подробнее можно почитать в книге "Spring в действии" (8.2.3. Поиск представлений).

Comment: По идее префиксы и суффиксы не должны повлиять, какая разница - я их пропишу вручную или это будет сделано автоматически. Да и в контроллер я же не попадаю все равно. Но всё же попробовал - не помогло

Comment: А за книгу - спасибо, почитаю )

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите отобразить вью и используете `InternalResourceViewResolver`, то в контроллере что-то вроде :

```
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public ModelAndView home(Locale locale, ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Welcome home from form portlet! the client locale is " + locale.toString());
    model.setViewName("index");
    return model;
}
```

В web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

где url-pattern, путь где лежат Ваши jsp-файлы.
Иначе используйте что-то вроде:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" name="defaultCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>image/jpeg</value>
                        <value>image/png</value>
                        <value>image/webp</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.uraty.trainingplan.controllers"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

И такой например контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<String> getData() {
   return new ResponseEntity<String>("TEST!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

В дальнейшем Вам еще могут понадобится различные `HttpMessageConverter` и прочие приблуды для правильных кодировок и прочего.

Comment: В примере указал различные MessageConverter, из действующего проекта просто, вам можно их и не указывать, но в дальнейшем может пригодится. Когда столкнетесь с отображением русского языка и т.д.

Answer (score -1):

В url-pattern попробуте /*

вот так:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Теперь даже на автоматически созданный index не попадаю. Уже прогресс ) Но в контроллер всё равно попасть не могу